# I am trying to install CiviCRM to a Wordpress multisite, and getting an error Uncaught TypeError: method_exists()

Tags: installation, install, php8

I have been following the instructions for installing to Multisite here:

https://docs.civicrm.org/installation/en/latest/multisite/wordpress/

I created a separate civicrm database.

I set the CiviCRM installation (5.68.0) running. It did stuff for a minute or two, then came back with a fatal error.

The PHP log has an error starting with this:

---

```
Uncaught TypeError: method_exists(): Argument #1 ($object_or_class) must be of type object|string, int given in /home/<userDIR>/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/DataObject.php:2807
```

---

When I go to look at that line in the file, it has this:

```
if (method_exists($result, 'numRows')) {
            if ($_DB_driver == 'DB') {
                $DB->expectError(DB_ERROR_UNSUPPORTED);
            } else {
                $DB->expectError(MDB2_ERROR_UNSUPPORTED);
            }
```

In my searching on the web, I saw some comments that PHP 8 had made it a fatal error if the first parameter to method_exists() was not a string or an object.

In the stack trace, the first line is:

```
Stack trace:
#0 /home/<userDIR>/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/DataObject.php(2807): method_exists(1, 'numRows')
```

Hence it does seem that $result is passing an integer, not a string or object.

This seems like a check has to be made in the code, but it hasn't been.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're referring to was [fixed a long time ago](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-packages/commit/87aee426385676b8b6d58789ef9b3fdf0322a1a3), so it seems you are using a very old version of CiviCRM. Please upgrade to the latest version to get the latest fixes :)

Comment: No. As I said in my post I am trying to install Civi CRM 5.68.0. Which is the latest available.

Comment: That's strange because [line 2807 in 5.68](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-packages/blob/5.68/DB/DataObject.php#L2807) doesn't point to the code you pasted, and also the code you pasted no longer exists in 5.68 due to the fix I mentioned in my answer.

Comment: This is weird. The code I have / had was as described. I went and checked the ZIP file of the CiviCRM version. And the code is as you described.

I removed all the CiviCRM plugin directories and files from upload, deleted the CiviCRM database  tables.

Then re-extracted the CiviCRM plugin, and followed the istructions again. 

This time it worked. I even double checked the file mentioned, and the code is as you say.

I have no explanation for the bad file. I will note that at the top of the file it only references PHP up to v6. And no references at all to the version of CiviCRM